# Set the boundaries of a scrollable list

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jlist

How to set the boundaries of a scrollable list?

How would I set the boundaries of this list to make it not take up the hole application?
I have searched for about an hour now and found nothing that did what I wanted.

[image]

Here is what i have:

```
String alphabet[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D","E", "F", "G", "H","I","J","K",
                  "L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z" };

JList list = new JList(alphabet);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

Container contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

I have tried several different things without success.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Put the `JScrollPane` in the `PAGE_END` or `PAGE_START` (to constrain the height) after calling `JList.setVisibleRowCount(n)`

Comment: @AndrewThompson Noticed you passed the 80k mark a few days ago, haven't had the chance to congratulate you ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks.  :)  Of course, I'm now shooting for triple figure K.

Comment: @AndrewThompson aren't we all ;)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are using the default layout manager for a `JFrame`, which is a `BorderLayout`.

You could try changing the layout manager to something else, check out [A visual guide to layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more examples.

A `JList`s size is effected by a number of factors, you can provide hints to the `JList` about what you would like by using [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) which can effect the width (and indirectly, the height) and [`JList#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29).

This, of course, assumes that the layout manager in question will honor the preferred size values as specified by the `JScrollPane`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a  `LayoutManager` 
I'm assuming that you just want to "resize" the scrollpane

KR
Florian